# Getting XUL:Scale to show what numeric value is selected

Tags: firefox, xul

I'm working with XUL, and below is abasic slider/scale implementation:

```
<scale value="1" min="1" max="10" increment="1"/>
```

However I want a numbox next to it which displays the value selected in the slider, and maybe I didn't look hard enough in the XUL tutorial, but I couldn't find a feasible answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window id="yourwindow"
        xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
  <scale value="1" min="1" max="10" increment="1" id="a"/>
  <textbox readonly="true" observes="a"/>
</window>
```

Comment: In javascript you can get the current value of slider by this code :  document.getElementById('slider').value

Comment: Hey @nickolay can you explain where you found the `observes` attribute from? I want to document it on MDN but can't find out about this thing. So like where did you learn of this?

Comment: @Noitidart: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Tutorial/Broadcasters_and_Observers

Comment: Whoa! Super cool fast reply and super awesome doc! Thanks man!