# How do I access the correct XUL scale changed value

Tags: xml, firefox, firefox-addon, onchange, xul

I'm building a 'classic' Firefox XUL overlay extension. In this extension I want to include a [XUL `scale` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/scale).

I'm trying to read out the updated value of the `scale` element, if the user changed the position of the slider. However, I can't get the updated value — the value keeps staying at the starting position.

<sup><edit>

One important thing to note though is that you need the [Classic Theme Restorer add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/), and activate `View > Toolbars > Add-on Bar` (for Firefox 29+), to get my test case to show up in the status bar element, because that add-on's Add-on Bar restores the status bar.

</edit></sup>

The contents of `slider/chrome/content/slider.xul` are:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="chrome://global/skin/"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="slider.css"?>
<overlay id="overlay-slider" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
  <script type="application/x-javascript" src="slider.js"/>
  <statusbar id="status-bar">
    <scale id="slider" width="200" movetoclick="true" increment="10"/>
  </statusbar>
</overlay>
```

The contents of `slider/chrome/content/slider.js` are:

```
var Logger = {
  log: Application.console.log
}

var Slider = {
  onChange: function( event ) {
    // keeps giving me 0, in stead of the updated value
    Logger.log( document.getElementById( 'slider' ).value );
  }
}

var onWindowLoad = function( event ) {
  window.removeEventListener( 'load', onWindowLoad, false );

  var slider = document.getElementById( 'slider' );
  slider.addEventListener( 'change', Slider.onChange, false );
}

window.addEventListener( 'load', onWindowLoad, false );
```

It appears that the `scale` element behaves rather erratic, because I've also tried adding a [XUL `textbox` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/textbox) to the xul overlay, like so:

```
...
<scale id="slider" width="200" movetoclick="true" increment="10"/>
<textbox id="slider-value" readonly="true" observes="slider"/>
...
```

In this case the `textbox` updates appropriately and I can use it as a proxy to read out the `scale` value by changing the relevant javascript, to:

```
// changed 'slider' to 'slider-value'
Logger.log( document.getElementById( 'slider-value' ).value );
```

However, when I add `min`, `max` (and possibly other) attributes to the `scale` element the `textbox` element won't update anymore either and keeps staying at the `min` value, all of a sudden.

I've also tried a couple of variations of accessing data from the `onchange` event that gets passed to the event-handler, like:

```
Logger.log( event.value );
Logger.log( event.target.value );
Logger.log( event.target._sliderElement.value );
Logger.log( event.currentTarget.value );
... etc.
```

And on inspecting various properties of the event, I also noticed that the `_userChanged` property stays `false`, when I expect this to be `true`, since the `scale` was not altered programmatically, but by the user.

Are these bugs in the `scale` element? Or am I missing some vital information here, to read out the correct values?

---

<sup>I'm testing the extension in an instance of Firefox with `-no-remote -P development` arguments with an [extension proxy file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Firefox_extension_proxy_file), on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and Xubuntu 14.04 (although I doubt that this is relevant).</sup>

---

<edit>
I did some more testing, after reading [Noitidart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24845765/165154), and found out that overlaying the `scale` element in the status bar element appears to be the cause of my problems. All works as intended now, if I overlay my `scale` and observing `textbox` elements directly in either the Add-on Toolbar or the Additional Toolbar of the Classic Theme Restorer add-on, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="chrome://global/skin/"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="slider.css"?>
<overlay id="overlay-slider" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
  <script type="application/x-javascript" src="slider.js"/>
  <toolbar id="ctraddon_addon-bar"> <!-- or: id="ctraddon_extra-bar" -->
    <scale id="slider-simple" class="slider" movetoclick="true" increment="10"/>
    <textbox id="slider-simple-textbox" class="textbox" readonly="true" observes="slider-simple"/>
    <scale id="slider-complex" class="slider" movetoclick="true" increment="10" min="20" max="80"/>
    <textbox id="slider-complex-textbox" class="textbox" readonly="true" observes="slider-complex"/>
  </toolbar>
</overlay>
```

</edit>

Comment: Can you set up some testable xul here: http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/xuledit/xuledit.xul  you'll need to whitelist the url with: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/remote-xul-manager/

Comment: @Noitidart That is weird: when I set up a test over there (with inline javascript), it works. When I copy this to my own environment, (including the inline javascript) it fails (keep getting the same value). Note, however, that in my setup I don't have the wrapping `window` element. Is that necessary perhaps? I'm unsure how to include the `window` wrapper element in my xul file. It won't show anything then. Do I need to change the `chrome.manifest` entry for this, perhaps?

Comment: @Noitidart Never mind the `window` wrapper element remark — on your suggested test url it also works without the `window` wrapper element.

Comment: @Noitidart I'm note really sure how to go further from here. Do you want me to share a test somehow? Do I just copy (and paste) the preview url (`data:...`) for this?

Comment: If you can just edit in your question with something i can copy post to teds xul tester ill copy and paste there and work with it. But can you make it re-sim the bug youre having

Comment: or just give me your xpi file for the add-on itself. ill install it. if u cant figure out how to replicate the bug in that ted tester

Comment: @Noitidart Thanks for helping me out. I need to figure out how to pack an xpi first though. I'll come back to you when I figured this out. Shouldn't take too long.

Comment: Do you have github? Just upload all your files there ill figure it out

Comment: @Noitidart ... and thanks again, for having a look at this. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Noitidart By the way, what doesn't work, in my environment, is: when adjusting `slider-simple` I only see the `slider-simple-textbox.value` change; when adjusting `slider-complex` I don't see any values changing. (Not in the UI's status bar, nor in the browser console's output)

Answer (score 3):

Ok I was able to fix the logging to the console. It properly gets the value. I had to use `.getAttribute('value')` instead of `.value`.

```
var Slider = {
  onChange: function( event ) {
    // read the slider value
    Logger.log( event.target.id + '.value = ' + event.target.getAttribute('value') );

    // try to read the associated textbox value (as a proxy to the slider value)
    var textBox = document.getElementById( event.target.id + '-textbox' );
    Logger.log( textBox.id + '.value = ' + textBox.getAttribute('value') );
  }
}
```

But now the weird thing is, the `slider-complex` textbox doesnt update even though the value is updating.

I don't know man I looked up on mdn the `observes` attribute and can't find any information on it.

```
<scale id="slider-simple" class="slider" movetoclick="true" increment="10"/>
<textbox id="slider-simple-textbox" class="textbox" readonly="true" observes="slider-simple"/>

<scale id="slider-complex" class="slider" movetoclick="true" increment="10" min="20" max="80"/>
<textbox id="slider-complex-textbox" class="textbox" readonly="true" observes="slider-complex"/>
```

that `observes="slider-complex"` is a new one on me. never knew about that, can you explain it to me, where did you find this? ill update mdn and maybe i can help you more.

Weird thing is though, that `slider-simple` works fine in console logging with `.value` and also the textbox updates appropriately. real weird. but `slider-simple` console logging also works with `.getAttribute('value')` so we just need to figure out whtats up with complex one. if i remove the `min` and `max` attributes from `complex-slider` it works fine but i cant explain this, something weird is going on.

The MDN slider page says this for the value ATTRIBUTE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Attribute/value

> For those elements, setAttribute("value", myValue) and getAttribute("value") do not access or affect the contents displayed to the user.

it has a value PROPERTY which is used for displaying the value, in the text box.

Comment: Hey, thanks again for having a look at this with me. I did some more testing, and it appears to work perfectly as-is now (no need for `getAttribute( ... )`) if I don't overlay it in the status bar, but directly in either the Add-on Toolbar or the Additional Toolbar of the Classic Theme Restorer add-on (I'll update my question with the adjusted XUL). So, it appears Firefox is not happy with scale elements (and the observing textboxes) in the status bar. I picked up the `observes` attribute trick from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1151326/165154) here on SO, by the way.

Comment: P.S.: Be aware that your MDN quote only applies to `menulist` elements, as per the preceding sentence `For user editable menulist elements [...]` in that section.